# Targeting all last (but not last-most) elements of a given tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML structure with three structures of some element and two `p`'s right under:

```
<some_tag></some_tag>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<some_tag></some_tag>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<some_tag></some_tag>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

In practice I have much more than just three structures (more like thirty) so I need automation.

I need to select each last `p` in the first two structures, but not the last `p` in the last structure.

### My problem

There seem to be no CSS way to do the selection I desire.

Considering an HTML way of wrapping each non-last, `some_tag` structure in some other element (like a `div`) I conclude I don't like this solution as it seems to me unaesthetic.

### My question

Do you know a way to automate the described selection via JavaScript?

Comment: I'd like to this to easily design the aforementioned elements with CSS.

Comment: Is it possible to warp a `<div>` for each section?

Comment: Will there always be more than one p following each heading? Your question is tagged [javascript], so would something like a loop be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, usually there will always be a `p`. My stance is that some loop will help.

Comment: You can style all the last `<p>`s in every structure and then, target the very last `<p>` on the page and remove the styling.

Comment: so, you want to select the last p in a h2 or h3, but not a h4 - seems fairly simple given the example you've chosen to use

Comment: @Titus this seems promising, but I don't know how to remove the styling of the very last after styling all lasts, especially as it can have a dynamic `nth-child` number.

Comment: @JaromandaX it will not always be a `h4` or anything else --- it can be any given tag but I still need all last `p` besides the very last one.

Comment: simply put, you want to select any `<p>` who has a next sibling and that sibling isn't a `<p>` (there is nothing **last** about any of the `<p>` except for the one you **don't** wan't to select

Comment: @JaromandaX "structure" is metaphoric here --- there is no nesting. Last is also metaphoric here because indeed as you point out these `p` I'd like to select aren't last in the CSS meaning.

Comment: so it's any `<p>` that has a next sibling, and that sibling isn't a `<p>` - isn't that what you want? I don't think you can do this with CSS - because there's no way to refer to next sibling (or children for that matter) in a way that the target element isn't that sibling or child

Comment: @JaromandaX I think it's a good way to put it.

Comment: what I mean is, you have `a+b` but the CSS target is `b` - i.e. selects any `b` whose previous sibling is `a` ... but, there's no CSS syntax equivalent (as far as I know) that allows you to target `a` whose next sibling is `b`

Comment: you should wrap them in a container that's the proper way to define a html structure. If you add a wrapper class it would be more easier to sort it out'

Comment: the way your structure is, you would need a css previous sibling selector ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with JavaScript, here is an example:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
let latestParagraph;
const paragraphsToStyle = [];

for(const element of elements){
  if(element.tagName === "P"){
    latestParagraph = element;
  }else{
    if(latestParagraph){
      paragraphsToStyle.push(latestParagraph);
    }
  }
}

paragraphsToStyle.pop();

for(const paragraph of paragraphsToStyle){
  paragraph.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<h3>h</h2>
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p>
<h2>h</h2>
<p>p3</p>
<p>p4</p>
<h1>h</h2>
<p>p5</p>
<p>p6</p>
```

This will only work if there is no nesting.

The script runs through all the elements on the page and when a non paragraph element is encountered, it adds the latest paragraph found to the `paragraphsToStyle` array. At the end of the first loop, the last paragraph on the page is removed from the array `paragraphsToStyle.pop()`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good HTML structure for what you want to do.  It will be much easier if you wrap each set of `hX` and `p` inside a container tag like a `div`.

Otherwise you are going to have to loop over each element with JavaScript and decide whether to apply styles (if the current element is a `p`, and there is a next element, and it's not a `p`).

Answer (score 0):

Is your layout created dynamically? You could always use css classes to handle this easily. If you are not able to control this with layout here is a quick way to do it:

```
#myLayout *:not(:last-child) > p:last-child {
  color: red
}
```

This code grabs every parent with a p child. It should ignore the last child sibling and always grab the last p. I would recommend replacing the * with a node or a css selector though to prevent unexpected results. I also recommend at least limiting possible issues by enclosing everything in a container like below.

```
<div id="myLayout">
  <div>
    <h2>h1</h2>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>h1</h2>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>h1</h2>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're assuming the `<p>` are children of `<hx>` - they are not, apparently

Comment: ok I see. That is a bit more complicated. The css-selector I gave should still work if everything is in groups like JohnDoea says.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** As others have mentioned, you may want to restructure your HTML so that it can work with selectors more easily. But if that's not possible, you can use JavaScript for this. In this case, all you have to do is see if the element is a 'p' tag and if the next element is not a 'p' tag:

```js
var children = document.getElementById('content').children;
for (let i = 0; i < children.length - 1; i++) {
  let nextTagName = children[i+1].tagName;
  if (children[i].tagName === 'P' && nextTagName !=='P') {
      children[i].classList.add('selected');
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <p>p 1</p>
    <p>p 2</p>
    <h3>Heading 2</h3>
    <p>p 3</p>
    <p>p 4</p>
    <h4>Heading 3</h4>
    <p>p 5</p>
    <p>p 6</p>
</div>
```

Comment: <p> is not enclosed within the heading tag, re-read the question please

Comment: your question is vague and unclear - considering NONE of the `<p>` you claim are last, are last in any sense of the word

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the edited question.